# Can Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia be used for Torah study?

Tags: tanach

According to Orthodox rabbis, can [Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblia_Hebraica_Stuttgartensia) be used as a basis for torah study?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not aware of an official metric to determine whether the differences are enough to render it effectively a separate text. I mean, the Rambam holds that even a single incorrect letter renders the text invalid, though most understand this to refer to changes that change the fundamental meaning of a word rather than k'tiv malei/chasser. We know that the Masoretic text is wrong on that front due to the few instances our texts departs from the Talmud's exegetical use of malei and chasser.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky indeed it is hard to know unless one has to compare between the two manuscripts with every single letter. That's what I think I will do when I get BHS, I  will compere it to a Jewish website Tanach letter by letter lol

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky What is the category of "separate text"? Every manuscript is different. Even most modern printed Tanakhs have differences between them. An astute student would be aware of all the differences in his study. For instance, a user here once quoted as proof to me a Malbim explaining a verse in Yechezkel. Turns out the Malbim there was commenting on a variant text he had, a variant which is in all likelihood is based on a typo.